# how do I give a name to redis instances

Tags: linux, redis

I have started two instances of redis. Given below is the command used to start the redis instances.

```
service redis start
service redis2 start
```

for redis the default port is used and I have started redis2 with 6380 port. If I am to use the same, redis-cli can be used for default port and I need to give redis -p 6380 for the redis2 instance.

Can I get the redis instances started by some name to easily identity what each instance will be doing? ps -aef is given below.

```
ps -awef| grep redis
redis    11498     1  0 09:30 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
redis    13285     1  0 10:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6380
```

Comment: Hey, could you link me the source from which you were able to have a second instance of redis, I can't figure out how to do that

Comment: Did you get the solution for it or still waiting? @Giuliopime

Comment: I think I just ended up using the same name, can't remember quite well atm. Using docker right now tho which is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the users who run each Redis instance different.

```
ps -awef| grep redis
redis     11498     1  0 09:30 ?        00:00:02 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
redis2    13285     1  0 10:00 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6380
```

Comment: I am running the instance from root.

Comment: If you do not have a specific reason, you do not need to run it from root.